# make part of an image transparent using PorterDuffXfermode

Tags: android, background, transparent

somebody please help me, i don kno where im going wrong, i've tried every possible thing here, but **same black patch appears** .. dont kno where im going wrong...

the first image is being drawn  on the canvas directly, then on a canvas object c2, i draw the overlayDefault image, den apply paint to it, and then back on the original canvas i draw the overlay_mutable that i got after using

```
overlay_mutable = overlayDefault.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

but still the image is drawn but on clicking only a black patch appears and underlying image is not seen!!

```
    public class PartTransparent extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new TouchView(this));
    }

    class TouchView extends View{
    Bitmap bgr;
    Bitmap overlayDefault;
    Bitmap overlay_mutable;
    Paint pTouch;
    int X = -100;
    int Y = -100;
    Canvas c2;

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mah_grp_pic);
        overlayDefault =     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.z_oceanblue);
    overlay_mutable = overlayDefault.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);  // convert to ARGB_8888 format,only den can it be put on canvas in next line..
    c2 = new Canvas();
    c2.setBitmap(overlay_mutable);
    c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null);

    pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
    pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); 
    pTouch.setAlpha(0);
    pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));  // Blur modes

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                X = (int) ev.getX();
                Y = (int) ev.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }           
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
    //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it                          
    c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, pTouch);
    //draw the overlay over the background  
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay_mutable, 0, 0, null);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

Comment: anyway, i found the solution, instead of "overlay_mutable = overlayDefault.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);"

use overlay_mutable=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Config.ARGB_8888);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answering my own question, I had answered in the comment section previously]

replace

> overlay_mutable = overlayDefault.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);"

with

> overlay_mutable=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: You save my whole day!

Answer (score -1):

`overlay_mutable = overlayDefault.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);` creates a bitmap which does have an alpha channel, but `hasAlpha()` will return `false`.

So all you need to do is call `setHasAlpha(true)` on bitmap created via copy (overlay_mutable).